# Isotope (lagging on load) once in Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, jquery-isotope

I am in the process of migrating my html prototype to WooCommerce, but upon page load you can see the product grids springing then correcting themself shortly after - http://sutsurikeru.com/ml

My HTML version: http://sutsurikeru.com/meeko - no issue with load

My WooCommerce version: http://sutsurikeru.com/ml - They are not 100% identical due to WordPress injecting alot of new JS libaries and I have also loaded a few extra JS references with some plugins I have opted to use.

To try and find if something I have added since migrating to WooCommerce has done something - I have disabled all plugins and used the exact same jQuery in my HTML prototype and I still get the issue.

My Call to isotope on HTML prototype

```
        var $container = $('.isotope');

        //isotope config
        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                gutter: 10
            }
        });

        $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
          $container.isotope('layout');
        });
```

My Isotope call on WooCommerce (includes infinitescroll)

```
    var $container = $('.isotope');
        var $finishedMsg = '<span>No more dresses to display</span>';
        var $msgText = '<span>Getting more dresses...</span>';
        var $loadingImg = 'loading.gif';

        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){ 
            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector: '.item',
                //transformsEnabled: false,
                //animationEngine: 'css',
                masonry: {
                    columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
                    gutter: 10
                }
            }); 
        });

        $container.infinitescroll({
              navSelector  : '#page-nav',    
              nextSelector : '#page-nav a', 
              itemSelector : '.item',
              loading: { finishedMsg: $finishedMsg, img: $loadingImg, msgText: $msgText }
          },
          function(newElements) {

            var $newElems = $(newElements).css({opacity: 0});

            $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){

              $newElems.animate({opacity: 1});
              $container.isotope('appended', $newElems, true);                  

                WireEvents();

            });

          }
        );
```

Full custom jQuery I've written for both sites

JS from sutsurikeru.com/ml - https://jsfiddle.net/mh6sc1jp/

JS from sutsurikeru.com/meeko - https://jsfiddle.net/x29xycqj/

It's driving me crackers and I feel I've exausted all options to whats causing the problem with the lagging issue - I have most likely missed something (something straight forward I bet!) but any guidence would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize isotope inside $(window).load(function(){ }); not $(document).ready(function () { }} and that will solve your issue.

With your site isotope is initializing before the load completes and is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Just made the change on my local build and it made no difference, still spring loads - i removed wp_head and wp_footer just to double check to make sure no rouge JS libraries were conflicting and its still the same. BUT it looks like the width of the container was just too short, so I increased it by 20px and it seems to had done the trick! The hearts flash but thats something I can deal with for now